# Settting a Spark Standalone Cluster using two different Windows machines

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to set up an apache spark Standalone cluster using two different computers (windows 10) of the same wifi network as slaves.
I can successfully set up the master using Windows bash(linux subsystem) and connect a slave from the same machine.

The problem is when I'm trying to connect a slave from a different machine (same wifi) using the local ip of the master. I even temporarily opened up all the ports of both the machines and mamaged to view the spark ui from the slave machine using the local ip of the master. But still trying to set up a slave on  master-local-ip:7077 didn't work.

I believe that the correct way is to use password-less ssh between them but I'm not sure how to configure it for local ip addresses using the windows bash. I tried to create the key and when I executed ssh-copy-id the connection refused.

Any suggestions?